# eclipse jetty:run differs to cli mvn jetty:run

Tags: eclipse, jetty, java

I have managed to track a problem where within eclipse I see no error, but anywhere outside eclipse the error exists.

The error I get when run outside eclipse is LazyInitializationException from hibernate - caused by a `${entity.service.id}` reference in the jsp.

Outside eclipse I have tried jetty standalone, mvn jetty:run from the command line, and tomcat. I've cleaned the projects, disabled workspace dependency etc. I'm using eclipse galileo, m2eclipse 0.9.8.200905041414, jdk 1.6_17, maven 2.1.1 (not embedded), jetty 6.1.22 (standalone and plugin).

How is that possible??

Answer (score 0):

oh my goodness. it works outside eclipse under jdk1.5.0_15 in windows, but not linux! I need it to work under linux. help!!

Comment: following my 'answer' which should have been a comment - here is the answer! indeed the jdk1.5.0_15 works, _16+ doesn't. So I'm thinking that it could be a bytecode thing. I changed to javassist and it worked! Then I noted I had an old hibernate version - the 3.3.2 now comes with javssist. So I'm not going to delve further....get a new hibernate!!